# ASP.NET Get physical filepath from URL

Tags: asp.net, url, filepath

Is there a way to get the physical filepath from an ASP.NET's URL?

Scenerio: I have an app that is on two severs, but it will now be on lots more, and each server puts it in a different physical file path. Right now I'm doing this:

```
//for server 1
if (Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path).Contains(".com"))
 { Application["StoreFilesPath"] = "E:\\Data\\rootsite\\f1\\appsite\\Upload\\"; }

//for server 2
if (Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path).Contains(".net"))
 { Application["StoreFilesPath"] = "E:\\Web\\rootsite2\\f34\\abc\\ghi\\appsite\\Upload\\"; }
```

But what I need to do is something like this:

```
//for all servers
Application["StoreFilesPath"] = getPhysicalFilePath() +"\\Upload\\";
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) on the server side in order to get the physical path of a file, then return it in the `Application` or `Session` object, similarly to what you are doing now.

As for the physical path of a URL - there might not be one, as URLs can be re-written.

Answer (score 4):

This `Server.MapPath ( "/" );` or this `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath ( "/" );` should give you what you need.

Answer (score 4):

This is now:

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/");
```