# Getting Filename from url in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Currently we have a solution that grabs the filename from the URL using this

```
currentFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url);
```

We found that if there are query strings attached that include characters such as quotes it returns with an error of Illegal characters in path.

For example if the url is

```
http:\\myurl.com\mypage.aspx?utm_content=This+Is+"Broken"
```

Then it won't get the filename. Is there a better, cleaner way to get "mypage"?

Comment: Can't you just remove the query string from the url before calling GetFileNameWithoutExtension?

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6015377/559144 and vote him up if it solves your issue ;-)

Comment: did you try Server.UrlEncode(url); before getting the file name ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833680/asp-net-get-physical-filepath-from-url

Comment: Please consider that URLs need not refer to files, and that names with no illegal characters can still be illegal filenames.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use this: [Uri.AbsolutePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx)

```
Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

Comment: `string filename = Path.GetFileName(new Uri(myUrlString).AbsolutePath);`

Answer (score 3):

I would just find the `?` and if it exists, strip the rest of the string, then use that to GetFileNameWithoutExtension.

For example:

```
        string url;
        int index;

        index = url.IndexOf("?");
        if (index != -1)
        {
            url = url.Substring(0, index);
        }
        currentFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url);
```

Comment: this is way more complicated and verbose than what the framework already offers: Request.Url.AbsolutePath

Comment: @DavidePiras: Why are you assuming that the URL being processed is the request url? The OP made no mention of this in the initial question. The solution I provided was a direct response to their posted code which only referenced a URL. This url could be from a log file, it could be from a referral string, or from a parsed HTML page with embedded references.

Answer (score 0):

use HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath instead of the full URL as parameter into the Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension method.

Hope this helps,