# How To Get the images filename which that stored in resource file .resx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, resources

I needed a way to store images, so i found the best way is to create a resource file and store them in it, however i choose the option {**Link at Compile Time**} so it creates a resource folder in the project,
but when i call for an image it returns **Bitmap Image file** instead of the image *URL* or *filename* or *image path*, I need it this way because i'm developing a web API so i don't wanna send an image but i want instead to send its URL/path so is there a way to get image URL/path from resource file since it's already there
here is an image explain where it is in resource file:
[image]

Comment: please don't check this as repeated if the answer is not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiled code has the resource (the image in your case) itself embedded. The file path of the resource is evaluated at compile time but is **not** included in the compiled code.

Unless you are using a convention like resource name = image file name, you cannot get its path.

It is the very purpose of resources to make you independent of files.

---

You should probably include the image name or image url as string resource instead of the image itself.

Use "Add New String" instead of "Add Existing File...".

---

See also SO question: [ASP.NET Get physical filepath from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3833680/880990)

Comment: so what the best way for dealing with this problem since i want image url not the image itself

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** want to store images inside your assembly file and return that images URL's in web responses, you can apply some name encoding scheme and return some resource name based strings, for instance **http: //www.mysite/stored-images/{resource-name}**, where resource-name could be **_6aa_Left**.

Additionally you should implement route handler, that for path **/stored-image/*** will write into response stream your actual image bytes from appropriate resource when image will be required.